# Titlesec and Babel incompatibility?

Tags: sectioning, babel, titlesec, incompatibility

I cannot find a way to change chapter style with babel included (for hungarian language). Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont}
{\LARGE\thechapter.}
{10pt}
{\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
[\normalfont]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}[0pt]

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}` line, everything works as expected, however, with babel it does not work. Is it possible to style chapters (and sections, etc.) while using babel?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get any error. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I don't get an error either. (MiKTeX 2.9 last time updated 2 weeks ago)

Comment: I'm using MikTeX 2.9, but I do not get any error, but chapter does not look like I specified with `\titleformat`, but looks like babel's default. With english babel `\usepackage[english]{babel}` it works properly.

Comment: The `magyar` module for `babel` does a lot of stuff `\AtBeginDocument` and this might be the cause. One possible workaround is to move the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` commands *after* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: The Hungarian support module for Babel restores the meaning of `\chapter` after `\begin{document}`, while not giving any method for overriding this choice.

Comment: Putting it into document group makes it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `magyar` module for `babel` does a lot of stuff `\AtBeginDocument`; amongst other things (as **egreg** noticed in his comment), it restores the meaning of `\chapter` after `\begin{document}`, while not giving any method for overriding this choice. One possible workaround is to move the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` commands after `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont}
{\LARGE\thechapter.}
{10pt}
{\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
[\normalfont]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}[0pt]
\chapter{First chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually I've found a way to solve this problem in package or class. Using `\titleformat` in `\AtBeginDocument` is useless, but the `etoolbox` has the `\AfterEndPreamble{}` macro which runs at the very end of the `\begin{document}`. Putting `\titleformat` into that makes `titlesec` work.